# Evidence for Quantum Zeno Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

What is (good quality) empirical evidence for the [quantum zeno effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect)?

How convincing is the agreement between theory and experiment?

I would appreciate hearing from those who have studied the research papers critically and can point out any existing loopholes in the experiments or in the interpretation of the data.

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect#Experiments_and_discussion)?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes i did. Doesnt have what i asked above. 
I am seeking the opinion of people who have independently looked at the evidence critically.